# Facing exception error while loading magento

Tags: exception

I am facing this error. Kindly give me a solution to resolve this.

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

> Error log record number: 1845623148

Comment: anyone plz..? give me a solution

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: Open the file /magento root/var/report/1845623148. and check the cause. if you unable to understand. please post.

Comment: I am using magento 1.9

Comment: could'nt got your point..please tell me how to do??

Comment: i've opened the file but could'nt find the cause..

Comment: just post that error that you show in thae file.

Answer (score 1):

The message you see is not the error itself. The number is the name of the file that contains the error info. On your server, in the root directory of your magento site, navigate to var/report and the file will be there. Open it, and you will know what the error is.

Also, if you want to see errors printed on the screen instead of a file, rename the file errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml.

Comment: file errors/local.xml.sample is already renamed to local.xml

Comment: Well then in index.php, uncomment the display_errors line. While you're at it, please go ahead and mark my answer as accepted bc I know for a fact that it's correct. Thanks